# Find objects in list that contain values from vector in R

Tags: r, list

My data frame

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame(col1 = c(1:49), col2 = sample(c(0:20), 49, replace = T))
```

My list

```
fields <- list(A = c(2:4, 12:16, 24:28, 36:40, 48:49), 
           B = c(6:10, 18:22, 30:34, 42:46))
```

I would like to create a new column that contains the name of the (vector) object in *fields*, which contains the number in df$col1

I have created a conditional for loop over *fields*:

```
col1 <- df$col1

for (i in col1) {

if (col1[i] %in% fields[[1]] == T) {
col1[i] <- names(fields)[1]

}  else if (col1[i] %in% fields[[2]] == T) {
col1[i] <- names(fields)[2]

 }
}
```

Although this works, and I can then assign the resulting new vector col1 to my data frame, this doesn't seem very efficient to me- especially because I also have lists with more objects. 
The reason why I want to do this: I would like to use ggplot and dplyr to grouping and summarising the observations according to their position in my lists (*fields*, but also other lists) . I hope it is clear from my question what I intend to do. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have created a more generalised function that contains a nested for-loop

```
find_object <- function(x, list) {  

for (j in 1:length(list)) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {

if (x[i] %in% list[[j]] == TRUE) {
  x[i] <- names(list)[j]
   }
  }
 }
x
}

find_object(col1, fields)
```

That is more or less what I want - but this is a nested for loop, and I have heard that this is bad... Does anyone have a better solution??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use `match()` after creating a data frame with `stack()`.

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- stack(fields)
mutate(df, whatever = foo$ind[match(df$col1, foo$values)])

    col1  col2 whatever
   <int> <int> <fctr>  
 1     1     5 <NA>    
 2     2     7 A       
 3     3    12 A       
 4     4    19 A       
 5     5     4 <NA>    
 6     6    18 B       
 7     7    19 B       
 8     8    13 B       
 9     9    13 B       
10    10     1 B
```

Comment: @Tjebo No worries. I just wanted to drop another idea.

Comment: I came across my old question by chance and decided after all that time to accept this one as the answer because I realised that using `match` has become my go to approach and I am using this a lot. It is short and sweet and also only using base R.

Comment: @tjebo I am glad that you like match(). Thanks for coming back to this after five years!

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to transform the `list` to `data.frame` and then do a join/merge:

```
library(dplyr)
fields.df <- stack(fields) %>% mutate(ind = as.character(ind))
df %>% left_join(fields.df, by = c('col1' = 'values'))
#     col1  col2   ind
#    <int> <int> <chr>
#  1     1     5  <NA>
#  2     2     7     A
#  3     3    12     A
#  4     4    19     A
#  5     5     4  <NA>
#  6     6    18     B
#  7     7    19     B
#  8     8    13     B
#  9     9    13     B
# 10    10     1     B
```

note: I use `left_join` from `dplyr` because you are using `data_frame`. The base R `merge` should also work.

Comment: @Tjebo `stack` is in base R. I noticed that the `stack` in `rlang` also give the seem results here.